# Should I set a domain on cookies and if so why?

Tags: security, cookies, setcookie

Should I set a domain on cookies and if so why? -

The cookie is used for a shopping basket, the platform is .NET

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to. If the cookie header field does not have a domain attribute, the effective domain is the domain of the request.

You will want to set the domain in specific scenarios, if you want to make your `www.website.com` cookie to be avaliable at `api.website.com` you will need to set the domain to `.website.com`.

Also, there is no way to make the `www.website.com` cookie be avaliable at a different domain by setting its domain (security issue).